# Propagating uncertainties of constants in division

Tags: standard-deviation, uncertainty, error-propagation

I have two constants, $A$ and $B$, with associated uncertainties $\sigma_A$ and $\sigma_B$, from observational errors, for example. I need to perform calculations with these constants, by for example making $f = A/B$. Therefore, I need to propagate the uncertainties from $A$ and $B$ to my function $f$.

Wikipedia provides the [following recipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty#Linear_combinations) for a similar case, but when $A$ and $B$ are **variables**, not **constants**, and the errors are assumed to be their standard deviations.

[image]

How do I compute the standard deviation $\sigma_{AB}$, when $A$ and $B$ are constants? Should I just make $\sigma_A$ times $\sigma_B$? Or moreover, **how do I propagate the uncertainties of two constants to their ratio?**

Comment: Are Ai and Bi dependent or independent ?

Comment: Because if non independent, then the ratio of mean **might** be different than the mean of ratios. Same reasoning for uncertainty.

Comment: They are independent, two measured quantities, not variables. Could be for example mass and speed of something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I learned that, when $A$ and $B$ are constants with uncertainties $\sigma_A$ and  $\sigma_B$, one just needs to add their relative uncertainties in quadrature, to propagate their uncertainties to a function $f(A, B)$, which may as well be $f(A,B)=\frac{A}{B}$.

$$ \frac{\sigma_f}{f} = \sqrt{\left(\frac{\sigma_A}{A}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\sigma_B}{B}\right)^2} $$